# Directives, Isolated scopes, Inheritance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I totally confused by these topics and really need a hand to survive. Huge thanks in advance.

```
<xxx:layout style="height: 100px; width: 100%" xxx-horizontal>
    <xxx:layout style="width: 150px; background: yellow">I need to know my parent's orientation (should be horizontal:{{orientation}})</xxx:layout>
    <xxx:layout style="width: 450px; background: green">I need to know my parent's orientation (should be horizontal:{{orientation}})</xxx:layout>
    <xxx:layout style="width: 200px" xxx-vertical>
        <xxx:layout style="background: red; height: 50%">I need to know my parent's orientation (should be vertical:{{orientation}})</xxx:layout>
        <xxx:layout style="background: cyan; height: 50%">I need to know my parent's orientation (should be vertical:{{orientation}})</xxx:layout>
    </xxx:layout>
</xxx:layout>
```

Briefly, I need to know parent's attribute(which managed by xxx-vertical or xxx-horizontal A-directive) in child's link function. This [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YsOzyUeXfz27xU6WLba2?p=preview) describes current "success".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want, but it doesn't use that layout directive, I don't know if you really need it since I don't know the purpose of your directives, but you shouldn't use transclude when you have other directives inside it.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjHmsYgLsTou5VjNtbnP?p=preview)

Comment: I've accepted your answer because I got what I asked for ;) Actually, this is not what I really need. I'm trying to implement kind of 'splitter system', but it seems to me that I chose the wrong approach, especially because of transclude.